# Get Elements Of webpage As String

Tags: html, vb.net, parsing, webbrowser-control

I am attempting to parse a page to find out if it has a string on it that I need so I can take the appropriate action. I would usually use

```
New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(URL).ToString
```

This cannot be used in the instance as I need to be logged into to view the page, because of this I have attempted to get the document Text from the web browser element once the page is loaded

```
RichTextBox2.Text = WebBrowser1.DocumentText.ToString
```

Unfortunately, this does not work as the string I am looking for is not within the source of the page, it also does not appear to be referenced in the source which really confuses me but appears within the elements tab within the google chrome Developer tools.

I have been looking around on how to get a list of all the elements on the web page so that I can just see if it contains the element I am looking for but I cannot seem to find what I am looking for.

TLDR: I am looking on how to get all the elements of a loaded webpage that do not appear in the web page source.

Side Note: I cannot seem to find the element being referenced using "src" and it does not appear to be within an iframe.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am completely stumped.

I have looked around but if you feel I have missed something please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested, I have found a workaround for my instance but this will not work and is only a bodge as there is a different value that only appears for the condition I am looking for not the actual condition.

```
        For Each element As HtmlElement In Me.WebBrowser1.Document.All
        RichTextBox3.Text = RichTextBox3.Text + (element.TagName() & "-->" & element.Id)
    Next
```

This will show some elements I assume on the page but not all of them in my instance and not the one I was looking for but could be a good place to start for others with my issue.